# Subtract every element in two lists of timestamps from each other, and assign corresponding ID in that row based on results

Tags: r, dataframe, mapply

I have 2 data frames of unequal lengths, each with a column of timestamps. I would like to return the corresponding ID contained in df2 to df1 as a new column if the time difference is less than 60 minutes, meaning that so I know ID#1 in df2 with a specific appointment time are responsible for some of the entries in df1. Each ID should have 8 entries in df1.

To calculate the difference between each element in df1 and df2, I've tried

outer(df1$DataEntryTime, df2$ApptTime, '-')

and got a matrix of results.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WV6Hx.jpg)

What do I need to do next to build a conditional statement so it can return the ID# to df1 based on the results?

Many thanks!

Comment: Looks like a good question. A reproducible example with a minimal dataset really helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Add the data in image as text, to recreate the problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.